# Override Button_click event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am developing a WinForms application using the MVP pattern. I would like to pass the button clicked tag value to the presenter. Because I want to get the `button.Tag` property I need the sender argument to be of type `Button`. How can I do this with out doing this:

```
private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button)
    {
        presenter.CheckLeadingZero(sender as Button);
    }
}
```

I am having to downcast the object to a button in the method parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point in checking the type using the `is` keyword if you're just going to use the `as` keyword, because `as` does an `is` check followed by an explicit cast anyway. Instead, you should do something like this:

```
Button button = sender as Button;
if (button != null)
{
  presenter.CheckLeadingZero(button);
}
```